# Visual Studio 2012 how to access text-file resources for user?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, file-io, resources, text-files

I have made a program so that the user can track there fantasy football team the code below is from one of the forms that allows the user to pick their team under a specific set of rules. The issue here is not writing to the file it is reading from the file that was written too.

This file is in my resources and it contains the players the user entered. The issue is that the user has to access this text file and at this point it does not matter if the user can access edit the file or not this is a personal project for one person; however the way I have it set up this program will only run on my computer since the path I would use is the full path from the text files properties.

I have tried using the properties.Resources.resource as seen below and most recently I have tried using Application.StartupPath + "/FantasyFootball.txt". I still have not yet tried reflection because I am not sure if reflection is needed for this. The idea should be that I publish this program and it should work on any computer;however I get an exception when I try and run it outside of visual studio that the AppData folder could not be found.

So the question now is what actually happens when I press the publish button in visual studio? I get the setup file and the application files folder and the actual.application file and this ends up in my bin folder in the release folder in the app.Publish folder. I do not yet have the experience to know what this all means or what to do with it any suggestions?

```
private void btnShowRoster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string masterRosterPath = Properties.Resources.FantasyFootball;/*
        this is where the problem is I am not sure what to make the path
        so that the user will be able to acess the file*/

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(masterRosterPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string playerIn;
        string[] fields;
        playerIn = sr.ReadLine();
        const char DELIM = ',';
        string player = " ";

        while (playerIn != null)
        {
            fields = playerIn.Split(DELIM);
            player = Convert.ToString(fields[0]);

            lbRoster.Items.Add(player);
            playerIn = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        btnShowRoster.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Click on a player to add them to your team", "Choose Team", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question, you are trying to access a file that you've imported in your project's Resources folder.

If I understood you correctly, the string returned by accessing the file resource `FantasyFootball` is actually the content of the text file, rather than the path leading to it. Therefore, you can use its content directly! No need for a file reader. When you will publish your application, it will be distributed along with it.

The contents of the resource were loaded into the string when you did:

```
string masterRosterPath = Properties.Resources.FantasyFootball;
```

You can then start parsing `masterRosterPath` directly.

---

### Expanding on the question

If you do decide to use resources to contain your user's data, you should note that resource files like these will not allow you to modify its content dynamically through your code.

If this is your goal, for example, you could manually create a file on disk at a predetermined path (like next to the executable, or a separate folder, or elsewhere entirely), before loading it if it doesn't exist, or during the first time the user runs the application. Then, you can just load the file, edit its content, and save it at will. Be aware that the contents of the file will be editable outside of the application!

Maybe this is what you were looking for instead of resources, but you could save that path using user Settings, instead of hard-coding it. These you can edit at will, and each user of the computer running the application could have a different path value.

If you have only a few fields about one player to save, you could even consider making them Settings entirely. It would make them easily manageable and accessible. You should also note that that these settings can also be edited outside of your application, as they are automatically save as an XML file, hidden away in the AppData folder. The settings will be loaded for the correct user when the application launches.

If that sounds interesting, have a look at MSDN on [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx)

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly using the masterPath = properties.resources.FantasyFootballTracker  to access the file will not allow the user to make changes to the files. Instead I would have to either create these text files outside of the project or use application settings? I have tried instead using the Application.StartupPath + "/FantasyFootball.txt" to get the path of the file however each time I run my application after publishing I get an exception that it can't find the AppData folder so I am not sure what I am supposed to do at this point or what I am looking for?

Comment: It can't find the AppData folder itself, or the path you've provided? The file won't be created automatically on installation that way.

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VWN40HAL.LPQ\B5YGWCN3.4JC\fant..tion_3460b927da4ef279_0001.0000_3396c544ffe1d0e3\FantasyFootball.txt'.
File name: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\VWN40HAL.LPQ\B5YGWCN3.4JC\fant..tion_3460b927da4ef279_0001.0000_3396c544ffe1d0e3\FantasyFootball.txt'

Comment: this is the exception generated when I run the setup file that I get after publishing the application user can be replaced with what ever the personal folder is named but this is where it is looking for my file and its not there so I am unsure of what to do

Comment: That's what I meant. Files, unlike Resources, are not created automatically. You need to check if it exists and create it first if it doesn't before trying to read it.

Comment: Try, for example, using the FileMode `OpenOrCreate`. This will create the file if not found when trying to open it.

Comment: That did the trick Thanks I guess I'll keep in mind that the file needs to be created in the future